# Пароли учетных записей в oracle apex

Tags: oracle, password, oracle-apex

Выполняю в приложение
begin
apex_util.export_users;
end;
после получаю вывод всех пользователей , у каждого есть p_web_password => '31314D14097C232D6E784A8055300A787259F30872181C03B22F653E7B19B9F45969C84E7555B02AC4573C28F8EAE8590F8FA640A21B81F408CEAC846192F902' . Сейчас делая доступ на тестовой среде , хочется понять как получить из этой строки пароль . Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы хотите из хеш получить сам пароль? Правильно понял?

Comment: @0xdb Да , хочется понимать можно ли вообще получить пароль таким образом

Comment: Нет, нельзя. А зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @0xdb Для понимая можно ли из этой строки получить пароль пользователя для обращения к api и приложению .

Comment: Ответил выше, нельзя. Повторю вопрос, зачем вам нужно получить пароль пользователя для обращения к api и приложению?

Comment: @0xdb Для понимания что при выгрузке всех пользователей из апекса нашего , пароли так не уйдут .

Answer (score 0):

Это хэш пароля, сам пароль вы из него не получите. Но можно создать пользователя в тестовой среде с `create user <user> identified by values <hash>`, и кто знает пароль сможет подсоединится.